# How to count how many times a word is repeated in a column for a specific category in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I've been stuck on this problem for daysss and I would appreciate it if someone helped me.
I have a dataframe, and the columns are:

```
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----   
0   PhraseId    93636 non-null  int64   
1   SentenceId  93636 non-null  int64   
2   Phrase      93636 non-null  object  
3   Sentiment   93636 non-null  int64
```

The sentiment is from 0 to 4, which basically rated the Phrase from good to bad. I added two columns which might be of help: Number of words for each phrase, and split each phrase into a list, the list containing the words inside the phrase.

What I want to do is create 4 bar graphs (a bar graph for each sentiment) showing the top 15 most repeated words for that sentiment. The x axist would be the top 15 words repeated in that sentiment.

Below, I pasted a code that I wrote which counts how many times a word is repeated for each sentiment. That would probably be needed for the bar graph.

**Sample data:**

```
       PhraseId SentenceId  Phrase                Sentiment SplitPhrase  NumOfWords
44723   75358   3866        Build some robots...    0   [Build, some, robots...] 52
```

**To count how many times a word is repeated for each sentiment:**

```
counters = {}
for Sentiment in train_data['Sentiment'].unique():
    counters[Sentiment] = Counter()
    indices = (train_data['Sentiment'] == Sentiment)
    for Phrase in train_data['SplitPhrase'][indices]:
        counters[Sentiment].update(Phrase)
        
print(counters)
```

**Sample output:**

```
{2: Counter({'the': 28041, ',': 25046, 'a': 19962, 'of': 19376, 'and': 19052, 'to': 13470, '.': 10505, "'s": 10290, 'in': 8108, 'is': 8012, 'that': 7276, 'it': 6176, 'as': 5027, 'with': 4474, 'for': 4362, 'its': 4159, 'film': 3933......}),
 3: Counter({'the': 28041, ',': 25046, 'a': 19962,.....
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense; however, please include sample data, not just the output of `df.info()`. Please see this link on how to ask a good `pandas` question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Okay, thank you, I attached an image of the sample data

Comment: no images! Please `read` the link I shared :)

Comment: I edited again, hopefully this is better. I also altered my question a little because I found a way to count how many times a word is repeated for each sentiment. I now need to create a bar graph based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to arrange each sentiment in a unique dataframe. Then, you can apply Numpy [`unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and `count` over the `Phrase` column joined text to count the occurrence of each word (for that specific sentiment group). Sort the resulting list by frequency count (`lambda i: i[1]`) and slice to get the top 15 words. For the bar graph you can use Matplotlib [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html#matplotlib-pyplot-bar) passing the list of words and frequencies.

Sample from *dataframe.csv*

```py
                                               Phrase  PhraseId  SentenceId  Sentiment
0   Live as if you were to die tomorrow. Learn as ...     15795        2568          3
1       That which does not kill us makes us stronger       860       62592          3
2   Be who you are and say what you feel, because ...     76820       67563          0
..                                                ...       ...         ...        ...
97  Others can stop you temporarily – you are the ...     61228       73530          2
98  Life has no limitations, except the ones you make     48984       93557          3
99    Peace comes from within. Do not seek it without     40774       61087          3
[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')
print(df)

def remove_stop_words(txt):
    txt = re.sub(r'[,.;!?-]', '', txt.lower())
    stop_words = ['the', 'at', 'in', 'of', 'a', 'is', 'to', 'by']
    stop_boundary = r'\b'+r'\b|\b'.join(stop_words)+r'\b'
    return re.sub(stop_boundary, '', txt)

MAX_WORDS = 15
SENTIMENT = ['Bad', 'Poor', 'Good', 'Excellent']

for n, g in df.groupby('Sentiment'):
    all_text = ' '.join(g['Phrase'].values)

    # optionally, clean txt and remove stop words
    clean_text = remove_stop_words(all_text)

    # find most frequent words
    split_txt = clean_text.split()
    word_count = [(word, split_txt.count(word)) for word in np.unique(split_txt)]
    word_count = sorted(word_count, key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)[:MAX_WORDS]
    x, y = zip(*word_count)

    # plot graph
    plt.subplot(2,2,n+1)
    plt.bar(x,y)
    plt.title(SENTIMENT[n])
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image: bar_graph_words]